# Why is this AJAX call returning the entire page contents?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to call the following webmethod found in one of my aspx page files:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetReportDetails()
{
    var reportDetails = DataAccess.Database().GetBusinessInterestReportDetails(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    var json = BusinessInterestReport.GetJson(reportDetails); 
    return json;
}
```

And this is the javascript that i'm using to call the webmethod:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'SummaryReport.aspx/GetReportDetails',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('An error has occured: ' + errorThrown);
      }
 });
```

The javascript that makes this ajax call:

```
$('.reportOption').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'SummaryReport.aspx/GetReportDetails',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('An error has occured: ' + errorThrown);
      }
 });
})
```

The `ScriptModule` config is already in the `web.config`. The break point is not even getting hit on the webmethod and the entire page's content is returned. Any idea what's causing this?

EDIT:
Using Chrome's debug console I found this error:

```
[ArgumentException: Unknown web method GetReportDetails.
Parameter name: methodName]
   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName) +516665
   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +168
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +75
```

Why would it not pick up the method name? I've also enabled PageMethods using `<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMain" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />`

P.S. Just realized that i'm calling it from within an iFrame. Could this have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: If the webmethod is not being hit, is it returning the code of a `500` or `404` error page?

Comment: Please show the HTML of the page that has your button (or whatever) in it

Comment: what does the variable json contain?

Comment: most examples I've seen include `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: You say you're calling this in your 'aspx' file - do you have PageMethods enabled in your ScriptManager?

Comment: @Rory: Please see update. I'm getting a 500 error.

Comment: Why not go for the: PageMethods.GetReportDetails(onSuccess, onFailure) syntax? http://www.itorian.com/2012/07/calling-aspnet-c-method-web-method.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It turns out that the inherits attribute was missing at the top of the aspx file.

So now I have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SummaryReport.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SummaryReports.Master"
Inherits="Web.SummaryReport"
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly add `contentType`, as its default value is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which is not you are after.

So you might want to revise your jQuery code a bit.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "SummaryReport.aspx/GetReportDetails",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('An error has occured: ' + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me. I should have caught that... I hadn't explicitly set my contentType.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` keyword from your `GetReportDetails` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write plumbing code (JSON serialization/deserialization) in your web method. Simply take/return models (.NET POCO objects):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetReportDetails()
{
    var reportDetails = DataAccess.Database().GetBusinessInterestReportDetails(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    return reportDetails;
}
```

and then consume:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SummaryReport.aspx/GetReportDetails',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        // the actual object will be inside data.d
        var reportDetails = data.d;
        // Now you could directly use the properties of your model
        // For example if your ReportDetails .NET type had a string property
        // called FooBar you could directly alert(reportDetails.FooBar);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('An error has occured: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

- We have explicitly specified the `contentType: 'application/json'` to indicate to the web method that we want to use JSON as transport mechanism
- We have gotten rid of the `dataType: 'json'` property because jQuery is intelligent enough to use the Content-Type response header and automatically parse the `data` parameter that is passed to your `success` callback.

I would also recommend you reading this article about [`consuming ASP.NET PageMethods directly from jQuery`](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

An addition I would like to contribute here from my experience in this problem.
if you are using a content page or master page, you can't call the WebMethod by accessing the page ,instead add a webserivce page and use it, please refer  to this link it worked with me.
http://forums.asp.net/post/5822511.aspx

I copied it here

Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function MyFunction() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

Then you can call the webmethod from master page or content page like following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function MyFunction() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'HelloWord.asmx/MyFunction',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (serverdata) {
                alert("Done  " + serverdata);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error  ");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

please be sure to uncomment the line :
System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService
in the webservice page since when creating the page it will be commented